# can't parse a (probably) valid json object

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a json object whith following code in python 3.

```
import json
str = '{"created_at":"Sun Aug 30 13:59:15 +0000 2015","id":637987951842951168,"id_str":"637987951842951168","text":"The Truth About the Iran Vatican False Prophet Anglo-American Western Alliance for Antichrist Israel: Palestin... http:\/\/t.co\/G79X164K9g","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003etwitterfeed\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":311859117,"id_str":"311859117","name":"Miko Furura","screen_name":"MikoFurura","location":"","url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":10,"friends_count":3,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":4,"statuses_count":1264,"created_at":"Mon Jun 06 05:32:44 +0000 2011","utc_offset":32400,"time_zone":"Osaka","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"EBEBEB","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"990000","profile_sidebar_border_color":"DFDFDF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F3F3F3","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":true,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/G79X164K9g","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1KvlIEu","display_url":"bit.ly\/1KvlIEu","indices":[114,136]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1440943155619"}'
c = json.loads(str)
print(c['id'])
```

when I execute the script, I got an error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 270 (char 269)
```

I have parsed many json objects with this code and can't understand what is wrong with it now, or what is wrong with this particular json object.

Regards.

Comment: One way to debug this is the load it into a json pretty printer and see if its able to parse or locate the error its pointing to

Comment: @ritlew I tried it and it's completely valid there.

Comment: Well, what is `line 1 column 270 (char 269)`?

Comment: It is near a backslash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use `r` in from of your string

```
str = r'{"created_at":"Sun Aug 30 13:59:15 ...}'
```

This helps interpret your `str` variable as a raw string so you won't have trouble with the backslashes inside the json string.

Answer (score 1):

In this part you could remove double quotes (") from html.

```
"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003etwitterfeed\u003c\/a\u003e"
```

to

```
"source":"\u003ca href=http:\/\/twitterfeed.com rel=nofollow\u003etwitterfeed\u003c\/a\u003e"
```

the extra double quotes are creating cyclic errors in JSON parser and HTML is fine without double quotes inside elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `r` before the string in `str`. I just tried it and it worked for me. Check out [Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for more info.

`str = r'{"created_at":"Sun Aug 30 13:59:15 +0000 2015","id":637987951842951168,"id_str":"637987951842951168","text":"The Truth About the Iran Vatican False Prophet Anglo-American Western Alliance for Antichrist Israel: Palestin... http:\/\/t.co\/G79X164K9g","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003etwitterfeed\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":311859117,"id_str":"311859117","name":"Miko Furura","screen_name":"MikoFurura","location":"","url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":10,"friends_count":3,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":4,"statuses_count":1264,"created_at":"Mon Jun 06 05:32:44 +0000 2011","utc_offset":32400,"time_zone":"Osaka","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"EBEBEB","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme7\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"990000","profile_sidebar_border_color":"DFDFDF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F3F3F3","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_3_normal.png","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":true,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/G79X164K9g","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bit.ly\/1KvlIEu","display_url":"bit.ly\/1KvlIEu","indices":[114,136]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1440943155619"}'`